# Image Submit buttons in Codeigniter - what am i missing?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got the following Codeigniter code to display a form, with two image submit buttons. I need to know which button has been clicked by the user.  Normally I just reference the name or value that is passed through, but nothing is passed from these buttons.  All other fields/textboxes etc.. on the form pass through ok, but nothing from these buttons....

.... what am i missing? I've been pondering this for a couple of hours and no help from the net either!

Ta

```
<? 
            $attributes = array('id' => 'formname','name' => 'formname');
            echo form_open('processform',$attributes); 
            $btn_input = array(
                'subtype'   => ''
            );
            echo form_hidden($btn_input);

            $btn_search = array(
                'type'  => 'image',
                'src'       => '/graphics/button1.gif',
                'id'        => 'button1',
                'name'  => 'button1',
                'value' => 'button1'
            );
            ?>
            <div id='1stbutton' style='text-align: center'>
                <? echo form_input($btn_search);?>
            </div> 

            <?
            $btn_search = array(
                'type'  => 'image',
                'src'       => '/graphics/button2.gif',
                'id'        => 'button2',
                'name'  => 'button2',
                'value' => 'button2'
            );
            ?>
            <div id='2ndbutton' style='text-align: center'>
                <? echo form_input($btn_search);?>
            </div>

            <? echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: What does each button's `name` value contain if you check the source?

Comment: var_dump($_POST) what is returning??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue (with Zend though)!
The thing is, the browser does not pass the “value” when input type=image.
to check wich button was clicked you could still reference the button by adding "_x" or "_y" to your button name (Ex 'Button2_x')and check the $_Post array against this.

```
if(isset($_POST['button2_x']))
{
  //button2 was clicked! 
}
else if(isset($_POST['button1_x']))
{
  //button1 was clicked go on!
}
```

If you need a look [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/157851/#761667).Same Issue Explained in Codeigniter forum

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not Codeigniter related, but related to HTML. "Image" type inputs will submit the x and y coordinates of where it was clicked, or "0" for both if not clicked. The `value` will not be submitted.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

> When a pointing device is used to click on the image, the form is submitted and the click coordinates passed to the server. The x value is measured in pixels from the left of the image, and the y value in pixels from the top of the image. The submitted data includes name.x=x-value and name.y=y-value where "name" is the value of the name attribute, and x-value and y-value are the x and y coordinate values, respectively.

However, this will still work for you as the button **not** clicked won't show up in the `$_POST` array. Here's a sample `var_dump()` from your form using your exact code clicking button 1 (but without the actual image available):

```
array(3) {
  ["subtype"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["button1_x"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["button1_y"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

So, it's a bit hackish, but you can simply do this to check which one was clicked:

```
if (isset($_POST['button1_x'])) // Button 1 clicked
```

Honestly I forgot about this until I just looked it up, as I never use `image` inputs. You might consider using a styled `submit` type or `<button type="submit">`. The latter allows HTML and is easier to work with - but beware of IE6...

With `<button>`, IE6 will send the *actual HTML content* as the post value instead of the `value`! Unfortunately I'm not kidding. However, you only need to check if it `isset()`, so don't actually rely on the `value` if you use this approach. Hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: Wesley, Many thanks - I hadn't actually realised that the value isn't passed - but then name doesn't appear to being passed either ... although that could be for the same reason I guess.  I'll go with adding _x to the name!   You mention about a styled submit button, not done that - presumably its a css styling?

Comment: Yes that's correct, with CSS. Is there another kind of styling? :) Just in case you weren't sure: you won't be adding `_x` or `_y` to the name in the HTML, only when you read it with PHP - do you understand? It's definitely unusual behavior. Try it out and you'll see. An yes, `<button>` tags are very flexible as far as what they can contain and how easy they are to style.